# git merge without commiting local changes beforehand

Tags: git, merge, commit

Maybe this has been answered before, but I can't seem to find it.
Let me illustrate my problem. I checked out a git repository and then done some modifications to the files. This has been some time ago and I now like to merge the latest updates from the repository with my changes. The problem is, that I dont use git as version control, since we use mercurial in our day to day operations. How can I get the latest changes without having to commit to git (which I can't do anyways).

Answer (score 1):

Stuff your changes in the stash (using git stash), pull from the remote repo with git pull, then use git stash apply (or pop, if you're confident it'll work).  No formal commits made.

```
git stash
git pull        # or: git fetch ; git checkout --force origin/master
git stash pop   # or: git stash apply
```

If there are conflicting changes between the upstream source and your own code, git can produce slightly more readable diff output in these situations with the following in ~/.gitconfig - YMMV, but it might be worth a try:

```
[merge]
    conflictstyle = diff3
```

Comment: That might work, but I cant confirm it... merging using tools is not feasable anymore, I copied a lot of code and made small changes to it, mergetools canot correctly identify the changes

Comment: Hmm... Are you saying the tools can't figure out what to do with overlapped and conflicted changes?   If so, I can understand, because that *is* a tricky problem with all toolsets I've seen.